# How to force AWS Console Item Explorer to show all columns?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When I `query` in the AWS Web Console's `Item explorer` for one of my `dynamodb` "tables", the resulting document does not show one of the "columns" that exists in the "record" (or doesn't show one of the "properties" that exists in the "document" if you prefer the document store terminology).

How do I make it show all the columns??

e.g. the following is the result from querying the dynamodb in the aws cli, but in the `Item explorer` of the aws console (on the web), the `thisThingsMissingInConsole` "column" isn't shown (and neither is it available in the `Select visible columns` preference)

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "email": {
                "S": "my@e.mail"
            },
            "thisThingsMissingInConsole": {
                "SS": [
                    "a",
                    "b",
                    "c"
                ]
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is the missing column present in most of the data, or in sparse records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, when confirming via the CLI, i accidentally checked the record in a different environment than I was browsing in the web console ‍♂️. So in my case it turns out that the property that isn't shown is actually missing .